# I am able to Access Emails from Java Mail Api

Tags: android, email, get, jakarta-mail

I am able to access (Inbox) emails from `JavaMail API` from this code

```
     public Folder getMails() throws MessagingException {
    store = imapSession.getStore("imaps");
    store.connect(mailServer, account.username, account.password);
    inbox = store.getFolder("Inbox");
    inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
    Message[] result = inbox.getMessages();

    return inbox;
}
```

I can show Subject in ListView Now My Problem is that **1.How to Show Email Content Body in android**.
& **2**.I want to access Yahoo mails & Microsoft email etc . I can access these emails through JavaMail API also. I have seen for this [K-9 mail](https://github.com/k9mail/k-9/tree/master/src/com/fsck/k9) also but i am not able to import this.

Any Help will be Appreciated,
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. JavaMail lets you access the message content, both plain text and html content.  How you display the content is a GUI problem unrelated to JavaMail.
2. JavaMail supports only internet standard protocols such as POP3 and IMAP.  You should be able to access Yahoo and Microsoft servers if they're configured to support those protocols.
3. Don't forget to read the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

1 You can use [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) to display message content as it will automatically render the `HTML` for you and will also provide the Zooming functionality.

2 You can access messages from any mail server, you just need the right properties.
For example in case of live and hotmail, host will be `pop3.live.com` and protocol would `pop3s` as MS Servers doesn't support IMAP.

Also Note: The Free version of Yahoo doesn't allow third services to access messages. You can only access messages from Yahoo if use their Premium service Yahoo! Plus.

Answer (score 0):

try to use following code to get mail content

```
private static String getMailContent(Multipart multipart) throws IOException, MessagingException{
    StringBuffer content = new StringBuffer();
    for (int x = 0; x < multipart.getCount(); x++) {
        BodyPart bodyPart = multipart.getBodyPart(x);
        String disposition = bodyPart.getDisposition();
        if (disposition != null && (disposition.equals(BodyPart.ATTACHMENT))) {
                // ................................
        } else {
            content.append(bodyPart.getContent());
        }
    }
    return content.toString();
}
```